# disable mutilple buttons on a single button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am fetching data in a table using ng-repeat in angularjs.the table contains id which i need to accept or reject. I want to disable other buttons ina row when one of the button is pressed.I am able to do it with tit using ng-disabled but the buttons of all rows are disabled..Can someone help..thankx

here's my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results "  >

<td>{{$index +1}}</td>
 <td>{{result.companyName}}</td>
<td>{{result.id}}</td>
<td>{{result.createdAt}}</td>
<td>{{result.modifiedAt}}</td              
 <td>{{result.Status}}</td>
 <td>
      <button class="btn"      ng-click="processStart(result.id)"> Approve </button>
    </td>
  <td>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="processReject(result.id)"         ng-disabled="showRejectButton" >
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>  Reject          </button>
```

Comment: you need to put a value of `showRejectButton=false` in your controller I think.

Comment: i have given it false..but the problem is ..it disables the reject button of all the rows..i want this is to done for a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have each reject button bound to the same variable for the ng-disabled condition, i.e. `ng-disabled="showRejectButton"`.

What you'll need to to is bound each of the buttons to their own variable.  You could do this using by making `$scope.showRejectButton` an array (then in your table use `ng-disabled="showRejectButton[$index]"`) or by attaching a showRejectButton to each of your result objects (then in your table use `ng-disabled="result.showRejectButton"`).

Comment: how to set vale true in controller.??